# CAST number as varchar, then update into another table as date

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, db2

I'll as brief as possible, but start by saying I'm a network guy, not a DBA.

SQL Server Enterprise 11.0.5343

Scenario - Need to get three columns (each with a part of a date) together, and then update another table with the full date.

Source table: UT210AP

```
Columns: 
  UTONMM (Utility On Month - 2 digit)
  UTONDD (Utility On Day - 2 digit)
  UTONYY (Utility On Year - 2 digit)
  UTONCV (Utility On Century - 0 = 19xx, 1 = 20xx)
```

I can select the data into a "date" with this code (the source data is on an IBM AS/400 linked server)

```
CAST(UTONMM as varchar) + '/' +
CAST(UTONDD as varchar) + '/' +
CASE WHEN UTONCV = '1' 
THEN 
RIGHT('20' + CONVERT(varchar(4), RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(4),UTONYY),2)),4)
ELSE
RIGHT('19' + CONVERT(varchar(4), UTONYY),4)
END AS UTON
```

And I get these results in the column I named "UTON":

```
4/6/1994
7/1/1988
11/14/1990
6/6/2014
```

QUESTION:
I have a nightly import job that runs, and I need to get the "date" (like 4/6/1994) into a field called TIME_CONNECT as part of this update statement from the job:

```
Update [responder].[Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS]
set CustomerID = lf.UTCSID
from [responder].[Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS] LEFT Outer Join 
[HTEDTA].[THOR].[HTEDTA].UT210AP lf ON [responder].[Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS].LocationID = lf.UTLCID
where lf.UTOFMM = 0
```

The "UTOFMM" in the code above is "Utility Off Month", I don't even care about checking for it's value, I just want to get the "UTON" date from the top select statement into the "TIME_CONNECT" field in the "Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS" field.

Comment: What is the data type of `time_connect`?

Comment: Consider asking your IBM i folks to build a UDF that converts the numeric dates into an actual date data type.  They could use this in a view `select idate((utoncv + 19) * 1000000 + utonyy * 10000 + utonmm * 100 + utondd, '*ISO') as Utility_on_date`   iDate is an open source package I use for this http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm

Comment: Regardless of anything else, you should be using a different string format during translation, one that isn't subject to localization issues (many countries in Europe flip the month and day ordering).  On SQL Server you want `YYYYMMDD`, _with no separators_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?  This copies the value into the field, assuming `time_connect` is a string.

```
Update [responder].[Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS]
set CustomerID = lf.UTCSID,
    time_connect = (CAST(UTONMM as varchar) + '/' +
                    CAST(UTONDD as varchar) + '/' +
                    (CASE WHEN UTONCV = '1'
                          THEN RIGHT('20' + CONVERT(varchar(4), RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(4),UTONYY),2)),4)
                          ELSE RIGHT('19' + CONVERT(varchar(4), UTONYY),4)
                    END)
                   )
from [responder].[Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS] LEFT Outer Join 
     [HTEDTA].[THOR].[HTEDTA].UT210AP lf
     ON [responder].[Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS].LocationID = lf.UTLCID
where lf.UTOFMM = 0;
```

If `time_connect` is a date/datetime data type, you can use `datefromparts()` (available in SQL Server 2012+):

```
Update [responder].[Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS]
set CustomerID = lf.UTCSID,
    time_connect = DATEFROMPARTS(1800 + UTONCV * 100 + UNONYY,
                                 UTONMM, UTONDD)
from [responder].[Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS] LEFT Outer Join 
     [HTEDTA].[THOR].[HTEDTA].UT210AP lf
     ON [responder].[Temp_RX_CUSTOMERS].LocationID = lf.UTLCID
where lf.UTOFMM = 0;
```

Comment: That looks quite promising.  I'll give it a whirl.  TIME_CONNECT is (datetime, null)

Comment: `UTONCV` is 0-based, so the second query will be off by 100 years.

Comment: Thanks for everything!
I've got it 'working' in SSMS, now need to integrate it with my import agent job.

Comment: SELECT
CAST(
 CASE WHEN UTOFMM > '0' 
 THEN
  CAST(UTOFMM as varchar) + '/' + 
  CAST(UTOFDD as varchar) + '/' +
  CASE WHEN UTOFCV = '1' 
   THEN RIGHT('20' + CONVERT(varchar(4), RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(4), UTOFYY),2)),4)
   ELSE RIGHT('19' + CONVERT(varchar(4), UTOFYY),4)
  END
 END
AS DATETIME) AS UTOFF
WHERE UTOFF > GETDATE() ORDER BY UTOFF DESC

Can I compare the value of UTOFF against todays date? This gets "Invalid column name 'UTOFF'.